# TypeError of select2 with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, jquery-select2, typeerror

I have successfully bundled local copy of select2.js with several *.js files through Webpack. However, it always throw a TypeError which warns that e.select2 is not a function. Interestingly, if I require the select2.js from CDN, it works at the initial page load, but throws the same error after refreshing the page.

This error never happened before I did the bundling.

Can anyone please suggest? Thanks!

By request, I'm sharing the the webpack.config.js below.

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
context: __dirname,

entry: {
    annotation: './assets/js/annotation_index',
    subject: './assets/js/subject_index',
    highchart: './assets/js/highchart_index',
    protocol: './assets/js/protocol_index',
    subscription: './assets/js/subscription_index'
},

output: {
    path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
    filename: "[name].js",
},

externals: [
    require('webpack-require-http')
],

plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'})
],

module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader', query: {compact: false} }, // to transform JSX into JS
    ],
},

resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', './assets/js/annotation'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: { jquery: "./jquery"}
},
}
```

Comment: Share your webpack.config file

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran I've just shared the webpack.config file above. Please suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Update 1**: 
Since OP loads jQuery using script tag, the better option would be to use external option to not bundle the jQuery.

```
externals: {
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    }
```

You can try with `ProvidePlugin` and `CommonsChunkPlugin` plugins

```
entry: {
  vendor: ["jquery", "other lib1", 'other lib2'],
  ...
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
       name: "vendor",
       filename: "vendor.js"
       minChunks: Infinity,
})]
```

Comment: Hey @JaganathanBantheswaran, thanks for your suggestion! I gave it a try, but I didn't have the luck. I finally solved this problem by configuring jquery in the externals section of webpack.config.js.

Comment: Good that you solved the issue.. This is one the way by which we can solve jQuery issue.